# React native android APK release build failed gradle

Tags: android

I have tried to build release build APK for my project. The project is perfectly working in the simulator. The problem is, showing some errors. I cannot trace what is the error about. Please check the below screenshot for errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0IAr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0IAr.png)

Comment: As per the error, it seems like `}` is required instead of `' '` at line 234 in your build.gradle file. Check your gradle file.

Comment: If you wrote the `build.gradle` file yourself, you probably forgot to use a closing `}` somewhere, not necessarily in line 234 (as 234 might be the end of the file, as the compiler could not throw a proper error). If you are using some tool to build your gradle file, run it again or try reinstalling your packages

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ReactNative\Portal_ITO_PROJECT\adroid\app\build.gradle` and find the line **234**.

You have missed a closing curly bracket `}` at line **234** of that file.

Use a text editor that can indicate the line number in file. i.e. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), etc.